# How to write 7.5 ( ± 2.5) × 10 − 5 in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I can seem to find a question like this one, but maybe I don't know how to properly describe it, so sorry if it has already been answered.

I am using `siunitx` but I want to put my range in parentheses after the value but before the exponential as in the title.

I tried `7.5 ($\pm$ 2.5)\num{e-5}` but that does not give you the correct format.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you are representing here: you seem to have an uncertainly but then mention a range!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should write

```
\num[separate-uncertainty]{7.5(25)e-5}
```

to obtain

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num[separate-uncertainty]{7.5(25)e-5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. ^.^  I will read your starter guide too.

Comment: Should it be `(2.5)`?

Comment: @sigur No. Why?

Comment: @karlkoeller, I'm not able to test the code here. I've just asked because you want `\pm 2.5` bu the code is `25`. I don't know if the period is inserted automatically.

Comment: @Sigur Of course it is.

Comment: @karlkoeller so if it `7.53\pm2.53 e-5-` you would write `\num [separate-uncertainty]{7.53 (2.53)e-5}`?

Comment: @Leeser `\num[separate-uncertainty]{7.53(253)e-5}` or `\num[separate-uncertainty]{7.53\pm2.53e-5}`

Comment: @karlkoeller. Sorry not at pc to test but I guess then if you want 7.5\pm0.5 e-5 you would have ....{7.5(05)e-5}. I see the logic now, I was a bit slow on the uptake. Thanks.

Comment: @Leeser You've got it!